# sessionStorage/localStorage not working with NavigationMixin

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, lwr, sessionstorage

I'm building a community on LWR. I would like to share information between 2 pages through *sessionStorage*.

**Page1**

```
handleSelection(event){
   this.selectedContactId = event.target.dataset.id;
   sessionStorage.setItem("selectedContact", this.selectedContactId);
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
       type: "comm__namedPage",
       attributes: {
           name: "Dashboard__c"
        }
    });
 }
```

**Page2**

```
connectedCallback(){
   console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedContact"));
  //output: null
}
```

**Observations**

1. NavigateMixin redirect well from Page1 to Page2, however the sessionStorage is always returning null value
2. If I refresh page2 manually sessionStorage works and return the right value.

**Workaround**

I am using `window.open("./dashboard","_self");`

but I would really like to use NavigationMixin which does a smoother transition between pages.

Comment: Maybe it's a race condition somehow? What if you check in the `renderedCallback`, or wait a tic using `await Promise.resolve()` in `connectedCallback`?

Comment: hey @sfdcfox yes I tried all of those but no much results yet. Very weird. Wonder if it's a navigationmixin behaviour or something. Same thing happen for loadScript.

Comment: Interestingly it's working with BYO(aura) template. So I guess it's LWR community issue then. Performance is amazing but still so many gaps. https://twitter.com/DavidBrowaeys/status/1509461899301175296

Comment: @brovasi did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't retry recently this was a big blocker for us as we use sessionStorage quite heavily. We are still on byo aura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I need to open a refreshed tab whether I open it directly or through Navigation Mixin from another tab. I tried getting values from session storage in constructor, `renderedCallback` and `connectedCallback` but these functions does not called/run when we move back and forth between the tabs or when we use Navigation Mixin and didn't prefer to use `window.open`

So, I tried using `CurrentPageReference` and it resolved all of my problem.

Whether I am opening tab directly or by using Navigation Mixin, its getting correct session storage values.

You need to just import this:

`import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';`

then write code like this:

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) { 
            this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
            if(Object.keys(this.urlStateParameters).length === 0) {
                if(sessionStorage.getItem('anyvalue')) {
                    this.yourvariable = sessionStorage.getItem('anyvalue');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this solution will help you also.